# How to get InvoiceLine from InvoiceQuery in QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

When I add an Invoice to Quickbooks with QBXML I use `<InvoiceLineAdd>` to add invoice lines. How do I get the invoice lines for an invoice when I am doing InvoiceQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IncludeLineItems` tag is what you're looking for. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceQueryRq>

      <RefNumber>ABC123</RefNumber>

      <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
      <IncludeLinkedTxns>true</IncludeLinkedTxns>
    
    </InvoiceQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: DUDE! You just rocked my world! You wouldn't happen to know how to get bill items with the bill query too would you?

Comment: And thanks for including txns also! I'm trying to get all the info I can from invoices and bills

Comment: @Tyler That same `<IncludeLineItems>` tags works for getting bill line items in a `<BillQuery>` as well.